# How can I use JavaScriptSerializer in c# to parse Json with unknown number of Keys and Values?

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, javascriptserializer

If I had a Json string with unknown number of Keys and values. How can I obtain all values into an array or object in c#?

In the following example I know there is "id" and "index" fields. What if I didn't know the Keys in the field?

In another context, What if the number of keys is large in number so that I Can't declare variables?

```
[{"id":"449342","index":0},{"id":"449343","index":1}]
```

I deserialize the above Json like this. What about the two contexts mentioned above?

```
JavaScriptSerializer js = new JavaScriptSerializer();
        AllLiTags[] Tags = js.Deserialize<AllLiTags[]>(LiOrder);

public class AllLiTags
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Index { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: You could deserialize it to a dictionary.

Comment: And how??? Any references?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9228671/javascriptserializer-deserialize-into-a-dictionary

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either deserialize into a dictionary, or grab the nuget package [Json.NET](http://www.nuget.org/packages/NewtonSoft.Json), ([documentation](http://james.newtonking.com/projects/json/help/)) which is more oriented towards this kind of usage.

Deserializing into a dictionary would look like:

```
var tags = js.Deserialize<Dictionary<string, string>[]>(LiOrder);
string secondOrderIndex = tags[1]["index"];
```

You'd lose type information (numbers converted to strings, etc), and I doubt it would deal with nested objects.

Using Json.NET would look like:

```
var tags = JArray.Parse(LiOrder);
string secondOrderIndex = tags[1]["index"].GetValue<string>();
int idx = 0;
foreach (var order in tags) {
    foreach (var prop in order) {
        Console.WriteLine("Order {0}'s {1} property has value {2}",
                          idx,
                          prop.Name,
                          prop.Value.ToString());
    }
    idx++;
}
```

Comment: @Subin If you do, say, `js.Deserialize<Dictionary<string, string>[]>>(LiOrder)`, you'll capture arrays of flat objects OK, but I'm not sure off the top of my head how well that'd cope with objects-within-objects.

Comment: You used it because u know that there are two keys and they sre string. Wat if I don't know how much keys there will be ie id, index, something, something etc.. Or if a large number of keys

Comment: @Subin Primitive types would be converted to strings. Yes, you'd lose the difference between 1 and "1", and true and "true", but if you didn't know the shape in the first place, that probably wouldn't be a huge loss. With [Json.NET](http://james.newtonking.com/projects/json/help/), you can definitely deserialize any shape of object graph. If you know how to navigate the graph and the types you expect, you can do something like: `var tags = JArray.Parse(LiOrder); var secondOrderIndex = tags[1]["index"].GetValue<string>();`